# formatting of a 2-D array into a text file

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, formatting, text-files

I have a 2D array and I want to export it into a text file. I have a problem with formatting. For example I expect to have this format:

```
  11 22 33 44
  22 33 44 33
```

but this code produces this format: [[11 22 33 44][22 33 44 33]]. I prefer \tab as distance between each two numbers in a row. Thanks in advance.

```
PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter("file");

for (int i=0; i<X.length ; i++){
pr.println(Arrays.deepToString(X));
}
pr.close();
```

Comment: YOu need to print each array element one at a time.

Comment: \n is used to create a new line

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest is using a piece of code that would fill in blank spaces so as to format it properly, lets call the method printWithFormat(String s). Using deepToString is really unhandy aswell, if you look at the specification, it gives you a complete representation of the array, well exactly how it prints it out into the file for you. I will now assume X is a 2d array.

Without the blank space formatting the code could look something like this, note that while this will give you a

```
11 22 33 44
33 44 55 55
```

it will look wrong with numbers of different lengths such as

```
11 222 33 4
3 44 55 5
```

hence why the need to fill it with whitespaces as needed

Anyway the non-whitespaced code:

```
for (int i=0; i<X.length ; i++){
  for(int j=0; j<X[0].length; j++){
    pr.print(X[i,j]);
    if(j<X[0]-1) pr.print(" "); //separate the numbers by spaces, no need to put a space at teh end
  }
  pr.println(""); //go to the next line
}
```

If you have trouble getting the whitespace formatting working, I believe its been done countless times and you'll be able to find it online.